# Why are apostrophes needed for a list with conj in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In closure, if you run the following code :

```
(conj (1 2 3) 4)
```

It'll error and say :

```
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

However, if you place an apostrophe before the list, it'll run fine

```
(conj '(1 2 3) 4)
```

My question is, what exactly does this apostrophe do, and why is it actually necessary for this list?

I've noted that this doesn't happen when you use a vector

```
(conj [1 2 3] 4)
```

In fact, even if you use an apostrophe `(conj '[1 2 3] )`, it'll still work fine and return the same result.

What exactly does the apostrophe do, and why does a list require it, but a vector does not? (Apologies if this is a beginner/stupid question, I'm still learning. A thorough answer would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between '() and (list) in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296857/whats-the-difference-between-and-list-in-clojure)

Comment: Try `'[1 2 x]` with `x` a variable, and there will be a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference betweeen `list` (the parentheses) and `vector` (the brackets), that lists are used for function calls, and vectors are simply vector literals.

An apostrophe is a reader macro for the [`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote), that suppresses evaluation. E.g., `(+ 1 2)` is evaluated to a 3 when read in from source file, but `'(+ 1 2)` is read in as a `list`, or [`clojure.lang.PersistentList`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java), conforming to the idea of *code is data* in lisp. On the other hand, quoting a vector is simply the [vector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java) itself.

So in your case, `(conj (1 2 3) 4)` when read in, it will try to call a function named `1` with arguments `2` and `3`, no wonder it fails. But a quoted list, or a vector can be appended with an extra element.